# Is there any `drush` command to delete any (previously exported) setting files?

Tags: drush, configuration

Can we use `drush` to simply delete any (previously exported) config-directory files?

Comment: Why Drush? What exactly do you mean by _previously exported_? Like all of them? Or particular chunks like a `git status` would bring up after running the export command on a clean git tree? There's also a list of all available Drush core commands: https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/all/.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**No.**

Simpy use your your operating system's file-browser to delete manually, there will be no issue (nothing depends on those files, except maybe importing).

Althoug, each time we export configurations, the old configuration files will be all deleted automatically,
and new files get created based on database (where the old files were).

> **Note** that not even `drush cdel` is up to the task,
> because `cdel` takes configuration object as input argument, and deletes it (from the active configuration) in the database, not the exported `.yml` files.

Answer (score 3):

Exported config files are regular files.  So, if you want to delete them, you can delete them like you would any other file-- either use your operating system's file manager, or use the command line.

There is no need for drush to support this because every operating system offers robust support for deleting directories of files.